# Многочисленные пересечения 2х функций. Как задать отрезок для расчета т. пересечений

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, математика

Есть две функции:
Одна из них прямая, а другая тригонометрическая, а значит цикличная - допустим, синус.

Прямая многократно пересекает синус в отрезке, допустим, от 0 до 100pi, а мне нужно найти точки пересечения в отрезке от 45pi до 60pi.

Есть ли какая-либо возможность поиска т. пересечений в заданном отрезке, кроме банального вычисления всех точек пересечения и проверки на предмет их нахождения в отрезке от 45pi до 60pi?

Comment: пробовали решить математически?

Comment: Математически? В ручную ? Графически - да ; онлайн - да!

Comment: Да, вручную. У вас же есть формула синуса и формула прямой.

Comment: @tym32167 Для наклонной прямой это не так  уж просто.

Comment: @MBo взял ручку, бумажку и понял, что, наверное, вы правы :)

Comment: в условии про наклон ничего нет

Comment: Я загнал в http://matematikam.ru/calculate-online/grafik.php две функции. y(x)=10*sin(x) и y(x)=0.6*x и допустим нужно найти корни в диапазоне от 0 до 3pi.
Эти корни не сама цель. Их в дальнейшем нужно использовать в других вычислениях. Просто тупо перебирать все корни на протяжении длинного отрезка как-то не по прогрессивному. Поэтому предположил что кто-то может быть уже об этой проблеме позаботился

Comment: Ну вот допустим есть уравнение `10*sin(x) - 0.6*x = 0`. Все решения находятся между противоположными пиками синусоиды, т.е. между точками `x = pi/2 + pi*n`. Можно численно решать уравнение на этих отрезках вправо и влево от x = 0, пока решения есть - так получим все решения.

Comment: это может быть вам интересно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766692/intersection-of-two-graphs-in-python-find-the-x-value
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318325/intersection-function-returns-multiple-coordinates

Comment: Спасибо Александр - супер! А также всем кто пытался помочь.

Comment: P.S. точнее не совсем так, все решения находятся между максимумами/минимумами функции `y = 10*sin(x) - 0.6*x`, но это тоже не проблема - нужно взять производную, а там уже нужно найти пересечения синусоиды с горизонтальной прямой. И максимальное/минимальное решения не выходят за x в точках пересечения y(x) = 0.6*x и горизонтальных прямых y = -1, y = 1. Как-то так.

Comment: Спасибо за поправку!